# Prevent Intercom API from rewriting links while sending messages

Tags: php, intercom

I'm using Intercom to send magic links -with Intercom API for PHP. I would link Intercom **not** to rewrite all my links with a Intercom-managed redirection system. Is there a parameter that can be set to prevent the rewriting from happening?

```
$body = " " .
"<html>  " .
    "<body>  " .
        "<h2>  " .
            "<b> Here is your magic link </b> " .
        "</h2> " .
        "<p>We have received a request for a magic link for the account bobby@so.com. Please find below the temporary link that will allow you to connect to your account. " .
        "</p>  " .
        "<h2>  " .
            "<a href='https://theurl/helpers/auth/forcelogin.php?id_user=xxx&randomkey=yyy' target='_blank'>Click here to login to your account </a>".
        "</h2>  " .

        "<i>Otherwise, copy this link in your browser's URL bar: https://theurl/helpers/auth/forcelogin.php?id_user=xxx&randomkey=yyy</i>".
    
    "</body>  " .
"</html>"; 
$client->messages->create([
"message_type" => "email",
"subject" => "New Password",
"template"=> 'personal',
"body" => $body,
"from" => [
    "type" => "admin",
    "id" => "zzz"
],
"to" => [
    "type" => "user",
    "email" => $_GET['email']
]]);
```

Comment: Please post some code to know what we are dealing with

Comment: Post has been edited.